# MySQL Update using Wildcard Replace

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ROUTE which has names like 'SAP_EAH_IN_RFC_GB_WMART' and 'SAP_EAH_IN_RFC_GB_TESCO' but I want this changing to %EAS_IN% instead of EAH_IN.  I have over 3k of entries.  Can I use the following?

```
UPDATE sap_xref 
SET ROUTE = REPLACE(ROUTE, 'EAH_IN', 'EAS_IN') 
WHERE ROUTE LIKE 'SAP_EAH_IN_RFC_%'
```

Comment: Turn it into a select and see for yourself :)

Comment: Thanks Shadow/jarlh, just the steer-nudge-confidence I needed to make this work.  Saved me a TON of manual laborious work!!!